# Capturing content between square bracket tags in PHP

Tags: php

I want to put content from bracket defined tags in text below and put all of them into an array, My attempts in PHP and `preg_match` function has been failed many times. What should I do in PHP using `preg_match` function?

```
$string="[restab title="name"]John O'Brian[/restab][restab title="telephone"]+15254636544[/restab][restab title="address"]Newyork, Wallstreet Ave, No 5[/restab]"
```

Comment: Please add your current attempts. Also show us what you want to extract and how you want to put it into an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for something like this:

```
preg_match_all('/\[[^]]+\]([^[]+)\[\/[^]]+\]/is', $string, $matches);
```

This gives you the following results:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(42) "[restab title="name"]John O'Brian[/restab]"
    [1]=>
    string(47) "[restab title="telephone"]+15254636544[/restab]"
    [2]=>
    string(62) "[restab title="address"]Newyork, Wallstreet Ave, No 5[/restab]"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(12) "John O'Brian"
    [1]=>
    string(12) "+15254636544"
    [2]=>
    string(29) "Newyork, Wallstreet Ave, No 5"
  }
}
```

You can add more brackets to capture text within square brackets.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at this library how it's done or just use/alter it.

https://github.com/jbowens/jBBCode

**Edit:**
If you only need the tags starting with restab. Perhapse this will suffice:

```
$text = '[restab title="name"]John O\'Brian[/restab][restab title="telephone"]+15254636544[/restab][restab title="address"]Newyork, Wallstreet Ave, No 5[/restab]';

preg_match_all("#\[restab title=\"(.+?)\"](.*?)\[/restab\]#",$text,$matches);
```

This will give every tag starting with [restab title="..."]

Comment: Giving URL is ok, but mentioning a bit code with its explaination would make it much better

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all("/\[[^\]]*\]/", $text, $matches);
```

The regex captures everything in the `$text` between `[` and `]`.
You need `preg_match_all()` if you want to match everything and not just the first instance